# At which point of reputation does Stack Overflow reward bonuses?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

When I reached 200 reputation points last week, I got a bonus of 100 from Stack Overflow, and I searched to know more about when and how these point appear, but no luck. When do you get freebies?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Basically, you get a 100 reputation "association bonus" when you link your account with another Stack Exchange site *and* at least one of your accounts has a reputation of at least 200.

From [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work):

> you associate accounts of two or more Stack Exchange network sites, and at least one of those accounts already has 200 or more reputation: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)

There really are no more freebies other than this. The 100 reputation association bonus is really just to allow you to skip past all of the new user restrictions, as it's assumed that if you have at least 200 reputation on a single Stack Exchange site, you've already begun to learn how the sites work.

From this point on, for any Stack Exchange account you create on any of the [Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites), you'll start out at 101 reputation.

Comment: So no more freebies? darn.. it tasted so good

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, every time you post a good question or answer and some users upvote it, you get free reputation. ;)  Sorry, I had to go there. ;)  Good luck and congrats on hitting 200 rep on SO!

Comment: Yea I know. Thanks, and congrats on hitting 14900

Comment: This is so great. I was struggling to get above 1 point for many months because some of my ideas on some subjects are far too innovative to be plausible. After very carefully studying climate change and changing the points for questions to be the same as the points for answers I finally rose above 200 points. I am starting to really enjoy the Stack Exchange peer review process.